# fitting text to div's width does not work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, text

I have this line of code

```
<div id="myid" style="overflow-y:auto; height:400px; width:100%; word-wrap: break-word;">
  <pre>Long content in here</pre>
</div>
```

so the text will fit in the `div`'s width but if longer than 400px a scrollbar will appear in the side.

This works in Safari mobile, Chrome mobile, IE desktop and Chrome desktop, but not in Firefox desktop (26.0). In FF a scrollbar appears in the bottom of the `div` horizontally

What am I missing? Is this the correct way to get what I want?

PS Text is included in `<pre>`

Comment: Works for me in Firefox http://jsbin.com/ociQeJO/1/edit

Comment: @davidpauljunior Set `<pre>` before/after the <p> and it will not...

Comment: If you were talking about `<pre>` you should have said that in the question. I've updated it.

Comment: So how do you get this to work?

Comment: @cokedude Check davidpauljunior's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use inline styling.

Second, remove your `word-wrap: break-word` from your div styles and set the following styles for your `<pre>`:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aTiKIlE/1/edit)**

If you're interested, [here's some examples of how and when to use the `break-word` and `word-wrap` properties](http://jsbin.com/OSuNatep/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `text-align: justify`?

Comment: Instead of something else? Or just add it there to? Because just adding it, makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in FF, and it worked. It had the vertical scrollbar you were looking for. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Did you wrapped the text in `<pre></pre>` ?Because if you do, does not work.